# Downloading large files from S3 to Lambda is faster without threads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to download binary file of size 15GB with python code in Lambda (to EFS because `/tmp` has a limit of 500 MB), but it takes too much time, so I have timeout error (Lambda's limit is 15 mins).

**In order to easily debug the code I'm working with file of 470MB (`abc.tar`), and on `/tmp`**.

I'm trying to make the code to download the file faster using multipart download.

this is my script without threads:

```
import json
import boto3
import time
import os
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s_t = time.time()
    config = TransferConfig(use_threads=False)
    s3.download_file('my_bucket', 'abc.tar', '/tmp/abc.tar', Config=config)
    print("time: ", time.time() - s_t) #print time took to download_file
    return{
        "statusCode": 200
    }
```

It took 25 seconds to download `abc.tar`.

When I change the config to be `use_threads=True`, it took 45 seconds (I ran it few times).
This was pretty surprising to me, because I thoughts threads should make it faster.

Nevertheless, I tried to use this config (as seeing from [this](https://medium.com/@ayushi.garg.1710/multipart-upload-and-download-with-aws-s3-using-boto3-with-python-using-nginx-proxy-server-bce35f3d5ba6) medium post) with multipart + threads:

```
config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=1024*20, max_concurrency=3, multipart_chunksize=1024*20, use_threads=True)
```

And I got timeout (after 70 seconds).

**How can I make the multipart download the file faster?**

Comment: Lambda is likely not the best option here, but be aware that the Lambda RAM size that you choose makes a difference because both CPU and network bandwidth increase with higher RAM sizes. Try it again with 3GB RAM option to see the difference. Or try [lambda-power-tuning](https://github.com/alexcasalboni/aws-lambda-power-tuning). Also, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTCaOQJvG6Y

Comment: As @jarmod says, how much memory are you allocating to your Lambda?  In tests in another language I'm seeing about 9 seconds with or with out the TransferManager.  I'm using a 1 and 2 GB Lambda and do see a bit of an improvement with 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to do a one-time transfer, it may be better to use DataSync and do it. That will allow you to transfer from S3 to EFS (or vice versa). You just need an agent on an EC2 instance and a task for it.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/what-is-datasync.html):

> Data migration – Move active datasets rapidly over the network into Amazon S3, Amazon EFS, or Amazon FSx for Windows File Server.

Is there a reason you want to do this in Lambda? Once it's in EFS, will you need to transfer it to S3 (or from S3 to EFS again)?

Comment: I want to do it once a day, for 50 files each 10 GB.